# How to ensure same BCrypt hash on different platforms?

Tags: android, java, bcrypt

Do I get it right that BCrypt hash depends on implementation? I'm using **jBCrypt** on client side (android)  and spring-security-core **BCryptPasswordEncoder** on server side (with the same strength=10) and I expected hashes to be identical but they are not.

My intention was to hash password in HTTP request body and only compare the strings on server side. Does it makes sense from security point of view?

Comment: are you passing the hash from the client to the server? or are you hashing the same password string using both libraries?

Comment: Are you using the same salt? Are you using the same version of bcrypt (there are a few with minor differences due to bugfixes)? Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: See also [Bcrypt generates different hashes for the same input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467819/bcrypt-generates-different-hashes-for-the-same-input), and [using bcrypt on same string gives different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197989/laravel-5-using-bcrypt-on-same-string-gives-different-values/39198006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My intention was to hash password in HTTP request body and only compare the strings on server side. Does it makes sense from security point of view?

Not really. While it makes it harder for someone to gain the clear text password, they don't have to. But an attacker won't have to care about the password. [They can pass the hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash). The hash is effectively the password, stored in clear text, in this scenario!

If users are perfect, and use unique, strong password, this would be equal to storing the passwords in clear text. As users are not perfect, and reuse passwords, it'd be a bit better than storing them in cleartext in real life. But not for your application.